# efficiently testing long boolean expressions in Excel

Tags: excel, boolean, excel-formula

Ok, lets say that I have two cells in Excel. They each contain a number. I realize that to compare the values of the numbers in these two cells, I can use a simple `=[cell1]=[cell2]` function. And I also realize that if I want to find the `negation` of a certain boolean value, I can use the `=not` function.

My question is simple, is there a more efficient way of coding long boolean formulas? I know in Java I could do something along the lines of `((!(cell1)&&(!(cell2)))||cell3`. But in Excel that simple expression turns into something along the lines of `=or(and(not(cell1),(notcell2)),cell3)`. Personally I like the shorter, more compact style of the java code.

Is there a short way to write boolean statements like this in Excel? Or am I doomed to use Excels clunky functions for the simplest of comparisons?

Also, this is a hypothetical question. I am just trying to figure out how to reduce the size of some of my longer boolean expressions. I don't have a specific error, just a lot of frustratingly long formulas.

Comment: No, there's no way to change this. Unless you are using VBA, but that's whole different story.

Comment: Damn. Well that is dissapointing. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in that case

```
AND(Not(cell1),NOT(cell2))
```

Can be replaced by:

```
=NOT(OR(cell1;cell2))
```

And, as in most of the cases you can replace AND by * and OR by + all the expression can be written like this:

```
NOT(cell1+cell2)+cell3
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a lifesaver. I was worried from the previous answer that it was impossible to short-hand my Boolean expressions. Even small bits of shortened code such as * and + are helpful.